# Viewing total number of coins mined for an Altcoin

Tags: transactions, blockchain, address, altcoin, altcoin-development

I am a newbie to crypt-currencies so for school, I forked a coin from litecoin to help me understand how it works and so far, I got it to work using a VPS with some other friends mining on it. I am trying out new things but I am having a hard time determining the total number of coins mined between all users. I can't seem to find the main ledger that is distributed among all the nodes, my question is how to view it and monitor how much of my altcoin is in each address. Can anyone help me figure this out? Where is the ledger or the blockchain? I would really appreciate it as I have be rattling my brain on this for the past few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally that would be the job of a block explorer application. You would have to build one for your altcoin if it doesn't exist. Otherwise you could issue rpc calls on the client and sum up all the block rewards.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Couldn't I use a currently existing one?

Comment: I guess as in, is it possible to use an open source one that is fairly easy to implement?

Comment: I can't comment on the grade of difficulty. Here's one you could start with https://github.com/iquidus/explorer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will start working on it right away!